# InteliJ cannot resolve name that is right near it

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I get "can't resolve symbol" error for the class that is defined right near the place it is used. 
I did invalidated cache and restarted the InteliJ several times, but it did not help.
What else could be wrong?

[image]

```
class Vehicle(speed : Int){
  val mph : Int = speed
  def race() = println("Racing")

}

class Car(speed: Int) extends Vehicle(speed){
  override val mph: Int=speed
  override def race() = println("Racing Car")
}

class Bike(speed:Int) extends Vehicle(speed) {
  override val mph:Int = speed
  override def race() = println("Racing Bike")
}

object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello")
val x = Bike(4)
  }
}
```

Comment: Since the code in the screenshot can't be copied, can you paste your code in to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: this works (the difference is that you are missing the `new` keyword before the Bike definition on the test object)

```
class Vehicle(speed : Int){
  val mph : Int = speed
  def race() = println("Racing")

}

class Car(speed: Int) extends Vehicle(speed){
  override val mph: Int=speed
  override def race() = println("Racing Car")
}

class Bike(speed:Int) extends Vehicle(speed) {
  override val mph:Int = speed
  override def race() = println("Racing Bike")
}

object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello")
    val x = new Bike(4)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you forgot the `new` @DraifKroneg

Comment: It does not work with the new for Bike, as well. However, if the rest of the code works fine in your InteliJ then it must be that my InteliJ is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create `Bike` object without keyword `new` and there is no companion with appropriate `def apply` function. Seems this confuses IDEA. To create class directly you need to use `new Bike`.